# Abrir videos(mp3/mp4) externo com PHP

Tags: php, reprodutor-de-video

Olá! Eu estou usando um "player"(em php) para abrir meus videos externo.

Porém o usuário não tem o controle da barra de duração do vídeo, ele não consegue ter o controle, nem voltar o vídeo, nem avançar, e isso me prejudica bastante.

**Player php 01**

```
$video = "http://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=b65e1fd886cd357";
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
readfile ($video);
```

Com o player 01, como eu disse, o usuário não tem controle na barra de duração.

Eu acabei achando um outro código, onde o usuário consegue tem o controle com algumas alterações.

**Player php 02**

```
$request = "video.mp3";
$file = $request;
$fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');
$size   = filesize($file); // File size
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte
header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $c_start = $start;
    $c_end   = $end;
    list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    if ($range == '-') {
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
    }else{
        $range  = explode('-', $range);
        $c_start = $range[0];
        $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
    }
    $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    $start  = $c_start;
    $end    = $c_end;
    $length = $end - $start + 1;
    fseek($fp, $start);
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: ".$length);
$buffer = 1024 * 8;
while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {
    if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
        $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
    }
    set_time_limit(0);
    echo fread($fp, $buffer);
    flush();
}
fclose($fp);
exit();
```

Com o player 02, o problema é que não consegue puxar de sites externo, tais como o blogger.

Preciso de uma solução para que o Player php 01 consiga tornar a barra da duração acessível, ou uma solução para que o Player php 02 consiga puxar de site externos.

> Eu preciso realmente usar o readfile php, não posso usar outro player.

Comment: Uma solução Javascript seria mais fácil. Seu servidor se comunicar com outros que não possuem webservice não parece muito seguro

Comment: @LuanPedro, não sei sobre a regra do seu negócio, mas qual a possibilidade de você baixar o vídeo para o servidor e fazer a chamada localmente?

Comment: Outra coisa, eu acredito que através do `@fopen($file, 'rb');` você talvez não consiga fazer essas tratativas remotamente pois não se trata de stream, ou seja, não é mantida uma conexão com nada para se obter ou enviar algo adicional, ele literalmente apenas abre.

Comment: Não posso usar javascript =/ > Sveen
Seria impossível, teria que upar milhares de arquivos para meu servidor > David dias

Answer (score -1):

Como a [documentação do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.readfile.php) diz para a função readfile,

> Uma URL pode ser utilizada como um nome de arquivo se fopen wrappers estiver ativo. Veja fopen() para mais detalhes em como especificar URLs como nome de arquivo. Veja também the Protocolos e Wrappers suportados para informações sobre que capacidades cada wrapper tem, notas de uso e informações sobre variáveis predefinidas fornecidas.

Você pode tentar usar a função [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$video_url = "http://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=b65e1fd886cd357"
$video = file_get_contents($video_url);
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
echo $video;
```

Ou então, pode optar por baixar o vídeo, salva-lo e usar o readfile :)

Answer (score -1):

Amigo use o javascript para isso, olha um exemplo

https://videojs.com/

Acessa esse site e olha o vídeo na página inicial...

```
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.5/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id='my-video' class='video-js' controls preload='auto' width='640' height='264'
  poster='MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg' data-setup='{}'>
    <source src='MY_VIDEO.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    <source src='MY_VIDEO.webm' type='video/webm'>
    <p class='vjs-no-js'>
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href='https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/' target='_blank'>supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src='https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.5/video.js'></script>
</body>
```

Não tem segredo... e existe diversos plugin para o jquery que faz isso também...

Vi o seu comentário agora, que existe milhares de arquivos e não pode baixar, então já que você está lendo os vídeos com PHP o outro caminho seria esse...

```
video.php
<?php
header("Content-Type: video/mp4")
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
?>
```

Agora é só chamar na página:

```
<source src='video.php?url=http://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
```

entendeu?

Comment: esse site aqui também usa um player do browser na página inicial https://elojobhigh.com.br/ olha ai o modelo

Comment: o javascript vai carregar ele no seu servidor, sem baixar...

Answer (score -2):

Fiz assim e functionou:

```
video.php

$file = "urldovideo.mp4";
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
readfile($file);
```